# Buscar dentro de un pdf con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Leo un Pdf encriptado y al momento de buscar la lista de abajo me dice que no encuentra nada, me parece que mi expresión regular esta mal

```
import PyPDF2
import re

file = open('imagen.pdf', 'rb')
pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
if pdfreader.isEncrypted:
    pdfreader.decrypt('')
    pageobj = pdfreader.getPage(0)
    pdftext = pageobj.extractText()
    tipo1 = re.match(r'(([a-zA-Z]{1,4})[0-9]{1,5}())', pdftext)
```

la expresión regular tiene que encontrar lo siguiente:

```
VGE07011_004.IFD  
VGH50052_007.IFD  
VIE01039.012  
VTGE0037   
Vie01025_001.IFD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por empezar `re.match` tal como menciona la documentación

> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the
>   beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.

O sea que solo va a encontrar el patrón al comienzo de la cadena, con lo cual lo que se puede hacer es un "split" del texto y recorrer línea a línea sino lo que puede hacerse es usar `re.findall`, también hice algunas modificaciones al patrón por que entiendo que no estaría funcionando de acuerdo a lo que quieres:

```
import re

text = """
VGE07011_004.IFD
Otra cosa que no quiero matchear
VGH50052_007.IFD
VIE01039.012
VTGE0037
Vie01025_001.IFD
"""
# letras de longitud 1 a 4 +
# números de longitud 1 a 5 +
# letras y números y un punto hasta el próximo caracter distinto
regex = r'[a-zA-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,5}[a-zA-Z_0-9.]+'

for m in re.findall(regex,text):
  print(m)
```

El output:

```
VGE07011_004.IFD
VGH50052_007.IFD
VIE01039.012
VTGE0037
Vie01025_001.IFD
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio muchisimo